# Replacing Resource files on new BlackBerry app version

Tags: blackberry, resources, upgrade

I am maintaining an existing BlackBerry application (implemented as a MIDlet). The application contains a number of data files that get bundled with the app as resources. Some of these data files need to be updated for a new version of the app. When the user goes to install a new version of the application (via URL of Jad file), it prompts them with the following message

"Persistent data exists for the application. Would you like to retain this data? "

If the user selects "Yes", it looks like the app continues to use the old resource files.

This is so surprising to me. First of all, am I losing my mind or will an upgrade really not overwrite existing resource files? Is there any way I can force it to?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that message is only relevant to existing RMS records. Are you positive that your app is still using old resources? That sounds unbelievably strange (even for RIM). Anyway, this should be easy to verify if you change some image resource you're using in one of your screens or something.

Comment: It definitely applied to the RMS records. After going through the code in great detail, I found it was taking data bundled as a resource and saving it as an RMS record. Don't ask me why it was doing this, as it makes it impossible for resources to be updated. Looks like I will be rewriting this app! 

Thanks.